# Flex Template Release Notes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, data-stream

I am currently making use of a Google DataFlow Flex template (Cloud Datastream to BigQuery) and I am looking at using a newer version of the template to what I currently have in production.

Is there anywhere I can view release notes for newer versions of the templates to show what bugs have been fixed or features that have been added - I cannot seem to find these anywhere?  Do these exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Release notes for templates are now published [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/releases)

Answer (score 1):

This is good feedback. Thanks Mark. We don't currently have 'official' release notes for individual templates, so that's something we should work on...

For now, my advice would be to [check the commits for that template](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/commits/master/v2/datastream-to-bigquery) in our Github repository (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/). That way you can get info on what we're changing.

Comment: HI @Pablo - many thanks for this, I'll take a look at the GitHub commits - very helpful :)